# Select a news category in PHP

Tags: php, system, modular

Hi I'm new on the web and do not understand it well, sorry if I make one mistake. I'm from Argentina, my English is very poor

I am creating my site a news system with categories. The news is that according to the category selected, but if not select any category, then displays all news.

At the same time I create a modular system for the Web, which is the next:

```
<ul class="top_menu">
                        <li><a href="?id=noticias.php">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?id=reglamento.php">Reglamento</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?id=registro.php">Registro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Estadisticas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nuestra Historia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Preguntas Frecuentes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Foro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>


<div class="main_con">
 <?php
                                    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $pag = $_GET['id'];
}else{
    $pag = "noticias.php";
}
include "modulos/".$pag;
?>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that when you select a category fails me:

> Warning : include (modulos / 2) [ function.include ]: failed to open stream: No existe el fichero o directorio en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ index.php on line 75
>
> Warning : include () [ function.include ]: No se pudo ('., C: \ xampp
>   \ php \ pear \' include_path =) apertura 'modulos / 2 "para su
>   inclusión en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ index.php on line 75

the php code to add a new category is this:

```
<?php
include ('db-cnx.php');

if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && $_POST['enviar'] == 'Enviar'){
    if(!empty($_POST['catCategoria'])){
        $catCategoria = $_POST['catCategoria'];
        $sqlInsertCat = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sn_categorias (catCategoria)
                                    VALUES ('$catCategoria')", $db_link)
                                    or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Los datos fueron gurdados correctamente";
    }else{
        echo "Debe llenar el formulario";
    }
}
?>
<form name="categoria" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <p>
    Nueva Categor&iacute;a<br />
    <input type="text" name="catCategoria" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
    </p>
</form>
```

How I can fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's a VERY bad idea to include files via GET. If your security isn't right, you could access files you have no business touching.

Second, you're referencing a file that doesn't exist. Fix the path or filename and it should work.